SwiftData: Backing data could no longer be found in the store
I am new to SwiftData, and I am currently working on a document based SwiftUI + SwiftData application, running on iOS 18.2. I have been lately encountering this fatal error:
SwiftData/BackingData.swift:866: Fatal error: This model instance was invalidated 
because its backing data could no longer be found the store. 
PersistentIdentifier(id: SwiftData.PersistentIdentifier.ID(url: COREDATA_ID_URL),
implementation: SwiftData.PersistentIdentifierImplementation)

I have several SwiftUI views that hold references to SwiftData objects. My current thought is that the culprit is probably a view holding a reference to a SwiftData object that has been deleted in the meantime.
Given this hypothesis is correct, how can I deal with this situation?
(Checking the isDeleted property of SwiftData models does not yield a consistent result, see here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/how-to-check-whether-a-swiftdata-model-object-has-been-deleted)
(My experience with other frameworks would suggest removing all ORM code from the view layer - but given how much of SwiftData's observable "magic" only works in Views, this does not seem to be Apple's preferred way.)

Possibly related to how you handle your ModelContainer object (and ModelContext objects)

With SwiftData I use Query all the time it is the only way to stay current. I opt for “parent” relationships vs array relationships and do a lot of Query even for single items where I have the id.

Update: it seems to me that the culprits are SwiftUI views holding SwiftData models and also accessing their relationships. In some cases whose details I am still debugging, the BackingData of the relationships gets replaced with InvalidFutureBackingData, while the BackingData of the main SwiftData model stays valid.

The problem occurs when trying to access relationships of SwiftData models referenced by SwiftUI views after the application has gone to the background and come back.
It seems that SwiftData detaches relationships from the ModelContext when the app goes to the background, and replaces their BackingData with various subclasses of "FutureBackingData", which normally do not occur in case of a freshly fetched entity. (The BackingData of the main entity that is an input parameter of the View stays intact). Accessing any property of an entity that has a "FutureBackingData" results in a fatal error.
I could solve this by replacing direct access of the relationship with a Query:
let predicate: Predicate<RelatedEntity> = #Predicate {
    $0.mainEntity.id == mainEntity.id
}
self._relatedEntities = Query(filter: predicate)

